# Running test of a specific module in parallel with maven surefire

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

My project has a number of modules, each with their own tests.  The tests within **all** modules need to be run sequentially, but I want to run one specific module's sequential tests in parallel with all other modules for performance reasons.

What is the simplest way to I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to configure the sure-fire plugin of the one module to parallel mode? https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the `pom.xml` file of specific `maven` module (i.e. module in which tests need to run in parallel) and then add `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration as follows:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Please use version of surefire plugin same as being used in your module. This could be determined by checking `effective-pom` file and search for this plugin.

Also, `parallel` can have following different values: classes, methods.

Here, `classes` means that **test classes** will be executed in parallel and `methods` means that **test methods** will be executed in parallel.

Comment: I need the module to be run in parallel with other modules, but tests within the module to be run sequentially.  This looks like it would make test classes within the module run in parallel which isn't what I want.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?